# Saving ManyToOne-Relationships with Symfony an FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosrestbundle

I'm using symfony with FOSRestBundle for my project. I made this example out of my code to reduce complexity. maybe forgot to rename a variable.

I have problems saving a article that has ONE category. the categories are already existing in the database. I don't want to create new categories

I'm not sure what's the best practice to do the job. so I tried a few ways and documented the error messages (see The Form-Type)

### The Entities

```
class Article
{
  private $id;
  private $name;
  /* this is ManyToOne */
  private $category;

  function getId() {/* ... */}
  function setName($name) {/* ... */}
  function getName() {/* ... */}
  function setCategory(Category $cat) {/* ... */}
  function getCategory() {/* ... */}
}

class Category
{
  private $id;
  private $name;

  function getId() {/* ... */}
  function setName($name) {/* ... */}
  function getName() {/* ... */}
}
```

### The JSON POST

```
{
  "name": "testName"
  "category": {
    "name": "nameOfAExistingCategory"
  }
}
```

### The Form-Type

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
          ->add('name')

          // here i tried out several ways of saving the category
          ->add('category')
          // error-message
          //Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\\Entity\\Article::setCategory() must be an instance of AppBundle\\Entity\\Category, array given, called in \...../vendor\/symfony\/symfony\/src\/Symfony\/Component\/PropertyAccess\/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined",

          // OR
          ->add('category', new CategoryType())
          // error-message
          // A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Article#category' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\\Entity\\Category@000000000c958844000000003bf8ec58. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={\"persist\"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Category#__toString()' to get a clue


          // OR
          ->add('category', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
          ))
          // error-message
          // message":"category:\n                    ERROR: This value is not valid
      ;
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

### The Controller

```
public function postAction(Request $request) {
  $form = $this->createForm(
      new ArticleType(),
      new Article(),
      array('method' => 'POST'));

  $form->submit($request->request->all());

  if (!$form->isValid()) {
      throw new HttpException(Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $form->getErrors(true, false));
  }

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $article = $form->getData();
  $em->persist($article);
  $em->flush();

  return $article;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example:

The Entities

```
class Article
{
  ...
  private $category;

  ...
  function setCategory(Category $cat) {/* ... */}
  function getCategory() {/* ... */}
}

class Category
{
  private $id;

  ...

  function getId() {/* ... */}
}
```

The JSON POST

```
{
  "name": "testName",
  "category": 1
}
```

The Form-Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
      ->add('name')
      ->add('category', 'entity', [
        'class' => CATEGORY_CLASS,
        'property' => 'id'
      ])
  ;
}
```

The Controller

```
public function postAction(Request $request) {
  $article = new Article();
  $form = $this->createForm(
      new ArticleType(),
      $article,
      array('method' => 'POST'));

  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if (!$form->isValid()) {
      throw new HttpException(Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $form->getErrors(true, false));
  }

  if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();

    return $article; 
  }

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: `CATEGORY_CLASS` is the fully qualified class name of the Category Entity, and given >=php5.5 could be replaced by `Category::class`.

Comment: @k0pernikus Thanks for the info.. In my example, `CATEGORY_CLASS` is just a pseudo-code, it can hold values like `AcmeDemoBundle:Category`,, or `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category`, or `Category::class` (>=.php v5.5)

Comment: cool! this seems to work. the problem is that the frontend (AngularJS) generates the json like you see it in my question. is there no solution to use it like it is?